# UITableViewController background image stretched

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to set the background image for a UITableViewController. I've got the following code which does set the background fine, but the image itself is being stretched to about twice the usual size.

```
[[self view] setAutoresizesSubviews:NO];

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];

self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView;
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[backgroundView release];
```

The image is only 640x960 pixels.

I've tried manually setting the frame of the `backgroundView` but it doesn't change the size of the background image.

Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my expirience, you should avoid using

`[UIColor colorWithPatternImage: ... ];`

as it leads to some problems with picking the right image for Retina/Low-Res devices.

Try something more like this:

```
UIImageView* bgView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]] autorelease];

[tableView.backgroundView addSubview:bgView];
```

Also make sure you have two PNGs:

- Default.png - 320 x 480
- Default@2x.png = 640 x 960

Comment: That worked a treat! UIImageView manages to detect the image dimensions perfectly. And thanks for the tip about the two images :)